# Node.js request function adds slash to url

Tags: node.js, url, request

I am trying to use node.js to make calls to https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id=math but when I call the request function like this:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id=math', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
...
```

A slash is added, making the request go to https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id=math/ which returns empty. Is there a way to have the slash not be added? Thanks!

Comment: The closing quote of the url is missing

Comment: @FortuneEkeruo thanks, I had the quote in my code, must have gotten removed when trying to figure out if I should put `function...` on the next line or not for formatting here

Comment: how were you able to confirm that a slash is appended?

Comment: the 'href' property in 'response' object in callback

Comment: You need to figure out where the trailing slash is being added.  I rather doubt it's being added by the `request()` library as I see no options in that library for controlling that and it certainly couldn't just always do that.  My guess is that it's happening in some server-side middleware or perhaps in a proxy.

Comment: If you change your URL to `https`, it seems to work for me in node.js.

Comment: Uhhh, where'd you go?  16 hours ago I posted an idea that works and you haven't responded.  I see that you're probably new here.  This place doesn't work very well if you just post and disappear for a long time.

Comment: Yes I am new, I will check this more often in the future. Was spending time with family. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host site appears to have some bugs.  There are two ways you can work around those, but if the host site is your code, then you should just fix those bugs in the server code.

1. If you switch to `https`, then it works.  I noticed this because if you enter `http://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id=math` into the browser, it redirects to `https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id=math` and it works.  Looking in the network tab of the browser, there's a 307 response with a redirect to the https version of the URL.  The node.js also gets a redirect, but not the same one as the browser (more on this below).  So switching to `https` avoids the buggy redirect that adds the `/` onto the end of the URL.  This is likely a safe work-around.
2. If you add an `&` onto the end of the URL, the regular `http` version of the URL will work.  This is a clear sign that it's some sort of server URL parsing bug that is causing the problem.  This is likely not a particularly  safe work-around because it's somewhat accidental that the redirected URL works (see discussion below).

---

When I do further investigation in my own node.js app, I find that if you set the `request()` option `followRedirect: false`, then you can see exactly what redirect is happening.  In this case, it is giving you a 301 redirect to `https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id=math/` with the slash on the end.  This is just a plain server bug.  You will have to either fix this in the server or use one of the above work-arounds.

All of this has been verified in a simple node.js test app.  For the redirect, it appears that the server is somehow detecting that it's a browser and sending the redirect if its a browser, but not in your node.js code.  I've looked at the browser and there are only four headers being sent with the request:

```
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: CD54EC492DF97F6357AFC5465E6D6D0C
```

For reasons, I don't understand the browser, gets a 307 redirect to `https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id=math` which is a correct URL.  I don't know why node.js gets the 301 redirect to the wrong URL and the browser gets a 307 reidrect to the right URL.  I tried simulating all the headers the browser was sending and I still got the 301 to the wrong URL.

---

Anyway, you have two possible work-arounds that work from node.js.  Interestingly, the adding of the `&` onto the end still gets a redirect with the `/` added onto the end as in:

```
https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id=math&/
```

but using that redirect URL does actually work probably because the `&` triggers the URL parsing to put the `/` into another xxx=yy segment of the URL separating it from the `dept_id=math` segment so it doesn't mess that one up.  This shows that the adding of the `&` is just a hack that causes the server bug to somewhat accidentally work.  I would not consider it a reliable work-around that might not accidentally break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Put an ampersand at the end of the url like so:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id=math&', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
})
```

This was tested on a fresh npm installation of request. I was able to replicate the error by leaving it out.